# AWS Glue script, error for Delimiter Not Found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

```
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from datetime import datetime
import os
from pyspark.sql.functions import current_timestamp
import sys

def move_file(bucket, key, filename):
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    dest_key = 'dcgs_abv/upload_archive_files'
    
    # Copy object A as object B
    s3_resource.Object(bucket, dest_key + filename).copy_from(CopySource=key + filename, ACL='public-read')
    s3_resource.Object(bucket,filename).delete()
 
## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

schema= "dcgs"  
table_bcs_output = "bcs_output_test"
redshift_schema_table_bcs_output = schema + "." +  table_bcs_output
bucket = 'bucket'
prefix = 'key/upload_files/'

s3 = boto3.client("s3")
response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket = bucket, Prefix=prefix)

for object in response['Contents']:
    key = object['Key']
    if '.txt' in key :
        file = os.path.basename(object['Key'])

        abv_data = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options("s3", \
                   {'paths': ["s3://{}/{}".format(bucket, prefix)], \
                   "recurse":True, 'groupFiles': 'inPartition'}, format="csv", delimiter='\t')
            
        abv_df = abv_data.toDF().withColumn("snapshot_day", current_timestamp())
          
        conparms_r = glueContext.extract_jdbc_conf("reporting", catalog_id = None)

        abv_df.write\
          .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")\
          .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://rs-reporting.cy2mjiqdtk9k.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:8192/rptg")\
          .option("dbtable", redshift_schema_table_bcs_output)\
          .option("user", conparms_r['user'])\
          .option("password", conparms_r['password'])\
          .option("aws_iam_role", "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/redshift_admin_role")\
          .option("tempdir", args["TempDir"])\
          .option("delimiter", '\t')\
          .option("quote","'")\
          .mode("append")\
          .save()
        
        move_file(bucket, key, file)
        
        job.commit()
```

I have a job in AWS Glue using Spark 2.4 Python3 (Glue Version 1.0).  I have tried every way I can find to set the delimiter for the Redshift load. I have tried `.option("sep",'\t')`, `.option("separator",'\t')` and quite a few others.

The file in question is a tab separated text file.  I have opened it with open office using the tab separator and ' for the text.

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, which I had to dig around a lot to find as it isn't specifically obvious in the docs here : https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/aws/amazon-redshift.html is the following:

`.option("extracopyoptions","delimiter '\t'")`

This will properly set the delimiter during the COPY command that is being executed.